# Adding padding and border to a figure without extending space?

Tags: floats, fbox, padding

I've added a border an padding to a figure. When I try to match the its width with the text I end up having a wider image than I intended. Is there a way to add border and padding without increasing the space? Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{caption}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure Title}
\centering
\setlength{\fboxsep}{15pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
\fbox{\rule{\linewidth}{10em}}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reduce the width of the image by 2 times the `\fboxsep` length and 2 times the `\fboxrule` length. This can directly be done with the help of the **calc** package (see the third example).

Note that in the below code, I explicitly specify the height of the image (to 3cm) so that all 3 images are displayed on the same page. For your case (if you really add images and not black rectangle with the `rule` command), don't specify the height of the image, so the aspect ratio is kept.

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\newcommand{\foo}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\begin{document}
\foo 

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure Title}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}
\end{figure}

\foo 

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure Title}
\centering
\setlength{\fboxsep}{15pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}

\foo 

\begin{figure}[h]
\caption{Figure Title}
\centering
\setlength{\fboxsep}{15pt}%
\setlength{\fboxrule}{0.5pt}%
\fbox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule,height=3cm]{example-image-a}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: What a thorough explanation! This solved my issue, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here I use a syntax similar to `\includegraphics`, but with one more argument to set the overall width, including the frame; the width of the picture will be reduced by twice the separation and twice the rule width.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlength{\framedgraphicssep}
\setlength{\framedgraphicssep}{15pt}
\newcommand{\framedgraphics}[3][]{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\fboxsep}{\framedgraphicssep}%
  \fbox{\includegraphics[
    width=\dimexpr#2-2\framedgraphicssep-2\fboxrule\relax,
    #1,% other options to \includegraphics
  ]{#3}}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-5]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\framedgraphics[height=3cm]{\columnwidth}{example-image}

\caption{Figure Title}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2][1-5]

\begin{figure}[htp]
\centering

\framedgraphics[height=3cm]{8cm}{example-image}

\caption{Figure Title}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[3][1-5]

\end{document}
```

[image]